# Вывод результата ip

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for, ip

Как выводить сообщение только тогда, когда все `ip` адреса, которые были в файле **ip.txt** считанные и доступные т.е. они все пингуются?

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    ips = f.readlines()
for ip in ips:
    response = os.system('ping -n 4 ' + ip)
    if response == 0:
        print(ip, 'all is up')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
    ips = f.readlines()

response_ping = 'all is up'
_ip = ''

for ip in ips:
    response = os.system('ping -n 4 ' + ip)
    if response != 0:
        response_ping = 'Что-то пошло не так.'
        _ip = ip
        break
    
print(_ip, response_ping)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! S.Nick , Вы как всегда выручаете!